# How do I run nested query with function that returns recordset?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

How do I run nested query with function that returns recordset ?

What I'd like to do is to parse TEXT field and split it to stems.

It should something like this

```
with strings as (
    select text
    from messages
    where channel_id = 12345 and text like '%#%'
)
select distinct token
from ts_debug('russian', strings.text)
where alias = 'word';
```

But obviously it doesn't work because `ts_debug` returns recordset.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lateral join:

```
with strings as (
    select text
    from messages
    where channel_id = 12345 and text like '%#%'
)
select distinct td.token
from strings 
  cross join lateral ts_debug('russian', strings.text) as td
where alias = 'word';
```

Answer (score 0):

maу be replaсe **strings.text** to **(SELECT text FROM strings)**

```
with strings as (
    select text
    from messages
    where channel_id = 12345 and text like '%#%'
)
select distinct token
from ts_debug('russian', (SELECT text FROM strings))
where alias = 'word';
```

OR to JOIN

```
with strings as (
    select text
    from messages
    where channel_id = 12345 and text like '%#%'
)
select distinct token
from strings 
INNER JOIN ts_debug('russian', strings.text) AS tsd ON true
where alias = 'word';
```